# Get ajax response when other page (loading ajax too) finished

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loading

I have a page that performs many ajax requests and a button that uses ajax for that page.
I want the button to give an alert when the ajax on the first page finishes.

But i get the response right away (while ajax requests on other page keep runing).
The first page is built from JS only.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible to answer without seeing the code. How are you checking if all ajax has completed?

Comment: Um, wouldn't it be so simple as: your loading script: `var loaded = false; ajax({success: (){ loaded = true }});` your check script: `if (loaded) alert('yay')`